# College Algebra: Find real-valued closed formulas for the trajectory $x(t+1)=Ax(t)$ ??

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, eigenfunctions

Hey so I have this problem on my webwork that I do not understand:

The problem says to find real-valued closed formulas for the trajectory:
$x(t+1)=Ax(t)$ where

$A=\begin{bmatrix} -0.8 & 0.6 \\ -0.6 & -0.8 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\overrightarrow{x}(0) =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

My thinking is that I have to make the dynamical system $x_{k+1} = Ax_k$

I solved for the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1} = \frac{-4}{5} + \frac35i$ with its respective eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} -i \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$

and  $\lambda_{2} = \frac{-4}{5} - \frac35i$ with its respective eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} i \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$

I made a formula $x_k = 1(\frac{-4}{5} + \frac35i)^k\begin{bmatrix} -i \\ 1  \end{bmatrix} + 0(\frac{-4}{5} - \frac35i)^k\begin{bmatrix} i \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$ which evaluates to

$x_k = 1(\frac{-4}{5} + \frac35i)^k\begin{bmatrix} -i \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$

but the answer is looking for a vector with 2 rows and 1 column.. what am I doing wrong??

Comment: The coefficients for $x_k$ are $i/2$ and $-i/2$, if you want $x(0)$ to have the correct components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $A$ is [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for angle $\theta = \pi + \arccos 0.8 \approx 3.785$ radians, which is approximate $216.9^{\circ}$. So $x(1)$ is $x(0)$, but rotated by this angle, $x(2)$ is $x(0)$ rotated by $2\theta$ and so on. You can write in as
\begin{align}
x(k) = A^k x(0) &= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos{k(\pi + \arccos 0.8)} & -\sin{k(\pi + \arccos 0.8)}\\
\sin{k(\pi + \arccos 0.8)} & \cos{k(\pi + \arccos 0.8)}
\end{pmatrix} x(0) \\&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
(-1)^k cos{(k\arccos 0.8)} & - (-1)^k\sin{(k\arccos 0.8)} \\
(-1)^k\sin{(k\arccos 0.8)} & (-1)^k \cos{(k\arccos 0.8)}
\end{pmatrix} x(0) \\&= 
(-1)^{k} \begin{pmatrix}
\cos{(k\arccos 0.8)} & -\sin{(k\arccos 0.8)} \\
\sin{(k\arccos 0.8)} & \cos{(k\arccos 0.8)}
\end{pmatrix} x(0)
\end{align}

Comment: How did you get $ θ=π+arccos0.8≈3.785 $?

Comment: Compare your $A$ matrix with general form of rotation matrix and solve $\begin{cases} \cos\theta = -0.8 \\ \sin\theta = -0.6 \end{cases}$.

Comment: If that's the case, instead of doing that, can  I write $arctan(-0.6/-0.8)$ to make this simpler?

Comment: In this case it will be $\theta = \pi + \arctan({3/4})$.

Comment: how did the (-1) appear?

Comment: $\cos(\pi k + t) = (-1)^k \cos(t)$ and similarly for $\sin$, for integer $k$.